# ASP.NET content placeholder in UserControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
<uc:MyUC>
    <CustomContent>
        <span id="name">johnny the assasin</span>
    </CustomContent>
</uc:MyUC>
```

and having that control able to render

```
hello <b><span id="name">johnny the assasin</span></b>
```

but I can't seem to find a way to expose a property that lets me write any markup I want just like as if I had a content place holder on my user control

Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to define a property of type [`ITemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx) in your control. E.g.

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
public ITemplate CustomContent { get; set; }
```

and then you could use it in markup like:

```
<uc:MyUC>
    <CustomContent>
        <span id="name">johnny the assasin</span>
    </CustomContent>
</uc:MyUC>
```

More could be found here: [How to: Create Templated ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx)

Comment: Found more details here: http://web.archive.org/web/20060615204657/http://90statehouse.com/forums/blogs/robertseder/archive/2006/06/04/201.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `[ParseChildren(false)]` attribute on an asp.net usercontrol, then it will not treat the html tags as control properties.

So in your class definition,

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
public class MyUC : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

}
```

Of course, if you want to have your user control actually have properties, *and* a property that is rendered 'as is',  you may have to create your main user control, and then have the CustomContent property be another usercontrol that just renders the content.

See [this link for a helpful article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/vinull/archive/2009/12/07/asp-net-creating-a-usercontrol-with-child-content.aspx).

Comment: the problem with this is events don't attach to controls like asp:Button, etc :(

Comment: mmm... no, it wouldn't.  I thought you wanted markup, not nested controls :)  Looks like you found an answer that worked though.